# How can I make a Slow Sliding Banner with jquery like tourradar.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, web-frontend

has anyone an idea how to make a slow sliding fullscreen banner with HTML Element -> like http://www.tourradar.com/ (see startpage section Everything You Want & More)

Is there any jquery plugin which can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code here, not a link to some website. You may also need to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: no code yet, was just thinking how tourradar made that slow sliding banner and if there is some plugin i.e. for jquery available.